# Soma de dois valores

Tags: php

Eu tenho dois valores:

```
Minuto1 = 00:00:00 e Minuto2 = 11:30:00
```

Eu estou utilizando o substr para ignorar os `:` e fazer a soma. Veja o exemplo:

```
$minuto1 = substr("00:00:00",0,2)*60 + substr("00:00:00",3,2); 
$minuto2 = substr("11:30:00",0,2)*60 + substr("11:30:00",3,2);
```

Após isso, eu pego os minutos que foram trabalhados:

```
$soma1 =  $minuto1 - $minuto2;
```

Caso algum dos dois valores estiverem como `00:00:00`, como eu posso fazer para ele me retornar após a soma ao invés de `-200` um `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um operado ternário:

```
$soma1 > 0 ? $soma : 0;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!